# How to validate integer range in Flask routing (Werkzeug)?

Tags: python, routes, flask, werkzeug

I have the below routing in my flask app

```
from foo import get_foo

@app.route("/foo/<int:id>")
def foo_id(id):
    return render_template('foo.html', foo = get_foo(id))
```

Foo can have ID between 1-300. Where can I have this validation?

I can have the validation inside get_foo. But, I am not sure if it's best practice. Should I filter it in the route definition itself?

Something like `@app.route("/foo/<int:id(1-300)")` (I don't know the exact way to do this.

How do I accomplish my need?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flask uses the Werkzeug routing system, after I checked the [Werkzeug URL Routing docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.IntegerConverter), I find it's possible to do range control in route rules.

> **From Werkzeug docs**
>
> class werkzeug.routing.IntegerConverter(map, fixed_digits=0, min=None, max=None)

So, you can set the keyword arguments `min` and `max` in the route rule like this:

```
@app.route("/foo/<int(min=1, max=300):id>")
```

If `id` is out of range, the request will get a response `404`.

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT for the comment :**

So there are two options to the range validation

1. in the routing
2. in the `get_foo` method

I think the choice depends on your own situation.

The first option will response `404` immediately if `id` is out of range, as mentioned above.

In the second way, you can validate the range of `id`, and do something you like to deal with the bad requests.

Comment: That sure does help. However, I was hoping to get more advice on the right way to do it. i.e. Justification to do it in the routing or in the get_foo method.

Comment: @San sorry for not seen the comment yesterday. The answer's updated, see if this helps.

Comment: I believe I should let the user know what he's done wrong instead of just throwing 404 in his face. I'll go with the second one. However, I got to know the integer validation in routing. Thanks a lot.